# application get crash because of ABI filters in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, vitamio

i am using [vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/) for play video and audio for that i have used gradle configure like below

```
 ndk {
               abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
```

it working perfectly on all android version.

now i hava added JNI code using [CMaker tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) for some operation but application is get crash on android version 7 only with below log

```
 Build fingerprint: 'xiaomi/mido/mido:7.0/NRD90M/V8.5.4.0.NCFMIED:user/release-keys'
 Revision: '0'
 ABI: 'arm'
 pid: 27944, tid: 28106, name: SyncAdapterThre  >>> com.mypackage <<<
 signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x29c
     r0 e4685300  r1 00000000  r2 074edc1e  r3 000004a1
     r4 00000000  r5 0000001a  r6 cf6b6740  r7 c63fecf0
     r8 c63feca8  r9 00000020  sl c63fecc8  fp 4ec4ec4f
     ip 2280b031  sp c63feca8  lr ec409776  pc cf6b6712  cpsr 60010030
```

> after changing NDK configuration like below it working

```
 ndk {
        abiFilters "arm64-v8a","armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86","x86_64", "mips"
           }
```

but now there is crash for vitamio on android version 7 only with below log

```
Build fingerprint: 'xiaomi/mido/mido:7.0/NRD90M/V8.5.4.0.NCFMIED:user/release-keys'
 Revision: '0'
 ABI: 'arm64'
 pid: 30859, tid: 30859, name: .onlineradioapp  >>> com.mypackage <<<
 signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
     x0   00000000000017a8  x1   0000000000000000  x2   0000007f6c200000  x3   0000000000000002
     x4   00000000000001a1  x5   0000000000008080  x6   0000007fa5c62000  x7   0000000000000000
     x8   0000000000000000  x9   0000007fa1e0c688  x10  00000000000001a1  x11  0000000000000000
     x12  0000000000000018  x13  0000000000000000  x14  0000000000000000  x15  00326d4469b4dcca
     x16  0000007fa26625a0  x17  0000007fa26098a8  x18  00000000ffffffff  x19  0000007fe80b04e0
     x20  0000007f798baa90  x21  0000007f6c3a1480  x22  0000007f798da000  x23  0000007f798da000
     x24  0000007f798ba000  x25  0000000000000000  x26  0000000000200021  x27  56c8e96642a3fb3d
     x28  0000000000000001  x29  0000007fe80b0480  x30  0000007f798b344c
     sp   0000007fe80b0480  pc   0000000000000000  pstate 0000000020000000
```

there is issue with ABI there is no implementation available for `ABI: 'arm64'` in vitamio can anyone help to me resolve this issue

thank you

Comment: check package's name ,it's consistent with jni

Comment: @KongJing can you please explain in details?as i mention it working with different `apiFilter` if i set `arm64-v8a` then JNI library loaded but vitamio file no loaded,if i remove `arm64-v8a` then JNI stop loading and vitamio start loading

Comment: I understand that the package name is inconsistent，if there delete                 `ndk {
               abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }`

Comment: Try to leave only one ABI, armeabi-v7a. Check contents of your APK - it's libs should contain all necessary files.

Comment: agree with @AlexCohn

Answer (score 0):

*hello-jni.c*

```
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env,jobject thiz)
```

*HelloJni.java*

```
package com.example.hellojni;

static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
    }

public native String  stringFromJNI();
```

I understand that the package is not the same reason

Comment: package  is same,there is no issue with that

Comment: delete ndk { abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips" }, can solve this issue?

Comment: in that case vitamio get crash because by default it build .so file for all ABI version and there is no implementation for all ABI version

Comment: is they any way so our JNI load .so file within `("armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips")`

Comment: If you want to add an armeabi-V8A directory, the following three-party armeabi-V8A related to the file, then you have such a file should have the corresponding armeabi-V8A version, or will be given.

Comment: May be not to configure 64-bit, open compatible, the program can not find 64-bit arm64-V8A folder, the program will automatically load 32-bit, so the file, this time will not be reported, successful operation

Comment: in that case .so file that is generated using JNI is not loaded

Comment: I'm sorry I did not answer this question

Comment: after deep checking found the issue `jstring  temp= env->NewStringUTF(s);` crash the apk where s is   char `s[len];` can you please help me related it crash only on android version 7

Comment: It seems no problem 
https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html#ci

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153844/discussion-between-om-infowave-developers-and-kongjing).

Comment: `NewStringUTF(s)` may crash if **`s`** is not a valid zero-terminated [modified utf8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8) string.